# A multiple choice field in a form is throwing exception on resetting database

Tags: django, forms

I'm running into a strange issue when resetting my database. A multiple choice field in a form is throwing exception

```
        Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x7f59df160510>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: app1_semester

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ......

      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/urls.py", line 3, in 
        from . import views
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/views.py", line 10, in 
        from . import models, forms
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/forms.py", line 11, in 
        class AddAssignmentForm(forms.Form):
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/forms.py", line 14, in AddAssignmentForm
        queryset=models.AssignmentType.get_assignment_types(),
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/models.py", line 180, in get_assignment_types
        return AssignmentType.objects.filter(semester=Semester.get_current_semester())
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmProjects/langs-dept/project1/app1/models.py", line 157, in get_current_semester
        return semester.first() if semester else None
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 260, in __bool__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql()
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/abdullah/PycharmVirtualEnvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app1_semester
```

If I comment below piece of code in forms.py, everything is working fine.

```
class AddAssignmentForm(forms.Form):
       assignments = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),queryset=models.AssignmentType.get_assignment_types(),required=False)
```

The method get_assignment_types() is a static method returning some list of values

models.py

```
 @staticmethod
    def get_assignment_types():
        return AssignmentType.objects.filter()
```

I can comment that line and do python manage.py makemigrations, but I wonder what is wrong ? Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in this line

```
AssignmentType.objects.filter(semester=Semester.get_current_semester())
```

You have to do proper migrations for model `Semester`

Comment: I am resetting the database., delete db.sqlite3 and trying to do migrations for the first time

Comment: You have to remove migration files also inside migrations folder in each app except __init__.py

Comment: exactly! that solved it., edit your response so as to mark it